# Other ways to embed images in HTML other than data URIs

Tags: html

I have an application that has many outputs. One of them is an HTML report. The result of processing is a lot of information, including 1 large image and a few smaller images.

I have been embedding them in the HTML document so the report is a single file that can easily be shared. Embedding using `data:image/png;base64,...` works but is incredibly slow to load compared to externally linking the images.

Is there another way to embed images in an HTML document that is a bit more responsive?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider load the image(s) by using canvas.

With AJAX Call

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  function loadCanvas(dataURL) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // load image from data url
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    };

    imageObj.src = dataURL;
  }

  // make ajax call to get image data url
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/dataURL.txt', true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
      // Makes sure it's found the file.
      if(request.status == 200) {
        loadCanvas(request.responseText);
      }
    }
  };
  request.send(null);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to embed images **in HTML**.
The other common option is to use [MHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) files which can be read/created by most web browsers (see the *See Also* section for other offline-html in a single file options), but MHTML while close is not really HTML.

Which brings me to:
If the requirement is to generate reports in a single file and HTML with data URLs doesn't cut it. Then, maybe you should consider other formats (*cough* PDF *cough*). Open source libraries for converting HTML to other formats are readily available.

Another option, assuming the images are charts is to use CSS to render them instead of generating images, but this will certainly be more difficult and will require changing the report generator.

Comment: Unfortunately is has to be HTML. There is JavaScript to interact with the images (which are not charts), so PDF is probably out. Although, I forgot about the MHTML format. Last time I used it was a decade or so ago and only IE really supported it. I'll have to look into it and see if it works as a replacement.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this (CSS/jQuery):

```
.img {
    background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat;
}

$("<img src='your-image.png'/>").prependTo(".img");
```